# Cypress becoming brown

Tags: trees, diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

Last Christmas I bought a tiny cypress in a pot.
Months passed by and it seemed to be doing good, so I moved it to a larger pot a couple of months ago.

But since a couple of weeks ago, it is becoming brown. It's still green inside, but the tips are definitely brown.

I gave it some "green plants" fertilizer, a couple of times, but I think it was even worse. I water it only when the soil is starting to look dry (every two or three days), and it's living outside in my balcony. I've tried moving it from direct sun to other spots, but it's the same with it.

Any clue on what can I do to make it look happy again?
Thank you very much!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to water it less. Conifers are capable to leave on dry for long time, and cypresses are also a plants which like dry.

Comment: What kind of Cypress? For instance Bald Cypress trees prefer moist soil so you wouldn't want it to get too dry.

Comment: @JaySoyer I don't know... I've seen bald cypress photos and the leaves seem different, so I don't think is the same cypress as mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably transplant shock. It's common whenever you relocate a plant and that includes upgrading pot sizes. What you should definitely not do is fertilize. People typically will add fertilizer for a plant in distress however that's the worst thing to do and you may end up killing it. If you used potting soil, there's already more then enough nutrients in the soil.

Plants (especially trees) are slow to show/recover damage. The bigger they are, the longer it'll take. Eg, you may have already killed your Cypress with that fertilizer, it'll just take a few months before it actually dies.

Come to think of it, this could also be fertilizer burn. Shows similar symptoms and this could have happened with just the potting soil. Depends on how fragile the roots were and what you used, but it still doesn't change how to handle.

The best thing to do is continue your normal care routines and wait. Put the Cypress back into the area it's being growing all this time as placing it in a more shaded area could be adding more stress. Water as you normally water.

The only thing you would have wanted to do different when upgrading pot sizes, is cut any roots that have become root-bound and water a little more often for about 2 weeks. Whatever you do, never trim back the leaves. So many places/people will tell you this, however it's a myth.